# Python: How to remove single quotes from list item

Tags: python, sql, list, amazon-redshift

I'm working on a bit of python code to run a query against a redshift (postgres) SQL database, and I'm running into an issue where I can't strip off the surrounding single quotes from a variable I'm passing to the query.  I'm trying to drop a number of tables from a list.  This is the basics of my code:

```
def func(table_list):
    drop_query = 'drop table if exists %s'  #loaded from file
    table_name = table_list[0]              #table_name = 'my_db.my_table'
    con=psycopg2.connect(dbname=DB, host=HOST, port=PORT, user=USER, password=PASS)
    cur=con.cursor()
    cur.execute(drop_query, (table_name, )) #this line is giving me trouble
    #cleanup statements for the connection
```

table_list = `['my_db.my_table']`

when func() gets called, I am given the following error:

```
syntax error at or near "'my_db.my_table'"
LINE 1: drop table if exists 'my_db.my_table...
                             ^
```

Is there a way I can remove the surrounding single quotes from my list item?

for the time being, I've done it (what think is) the wrong way and used string concatenation, but know this is basically begging for SQL-injection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not how psycopg2 works.  You are using a string operator `%s` to replace with a string.  The reason for this is to tokenize your string safely to avoid SQL injection, psycopg2 handles the rest.

You need to modify the query before it gets to the execute statement.

```
drop_query = 'drop table if exists {}'.format(table_name)
```

I warn you however, do not allow these table names to be create by outside sources, or you risk SQL injection.

However a new version of PSYCOPG2 kind of allows something similar

http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html#module-psycopg2.sql

```
from psycopg2 import sql

cur.execute(
    sql.SQL("insert into {} values (%s, %s)").format(sql.Identifier('my_table')),[10, 20]
)
```

Comment: It is ok if you your app is self contained and you are just injecting a predefined list.  There is no risk of SQL injection unless someone modifies your code, and then SQL injection is the least of your worries.

Comment: thanks for such a prompt answer!  your first solution works for me, but like you said, its still vulnerable to injection.  the only saving grace is that this should only be used by (theoretically) technically competent coworkers.  the 2nd one seemed like a better one, but the version of python I'm working with doesn't seem to be able to import that.  don't know why bc I'm on 2.7.5...

Comment: It is not vulnerable to SQL injection if it is not user imported data.  SQL injection is only an issue when outside sources are feeding data into your application, not within the application itself.

Comment: the data is coming from a csv

Comment: Then use the second example.

Comment: for some reason or other the required import didn't work.  what I've gone and done is just have separate query files (filenames in CSV instead of tables) as part of the source code.

Comment: It's only in the newest versions of psycopg2

Comment: yeah, sadly I'm dealing with a system administered by the cautious and for the paranoid.